# How can i change background color in a while loop - processing

Tags: background, while-loop, arduino, processing

I'm new to processing and trying to make a very simple program where i have an arduino that produces a seriel input (according to an analogue read value). The idea is a Processing window will open with a block color shown for 30 seconds. In this time all the readings from the arduino will be summed and averaged - creating an average for that color.

After 30 seconds the colour will change and a new average (for the next color) will start being calculated. This is the code i have started to write (for now focusing on just one 30 second period of green).

I realise there are likely problems with the reading/summing and averaging (i havent researched these yet so i'll put that to one side) - but my main question is why isn't the background green? When i run this program i expect the background to be green for 30 seconds - where as what happens is it is white for 30 seconds then changes to green. Can't figure out why! Thanks for any help!

```
import processing.serial.*;
Serial myPort;  


float gsrAverage;
float greenAverage;
int gsrValue;
int greenTotal = 0;
int greenCount = 1;

int timeSinceStart = 0;
int timeAtStart;
int count=0;
color green = color(118,236,0);


void setup () {
  size(900, 450);
  // List all the available serial ports
  //println(Serial.list());

  myPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[0], 9600);

}


void draw () {

  while (timeSinceStart < 30000) {
    background(green);
    greenTotal = greenTotal + gsrValue;
    greenCount = greenCount + 1;
    delay(500);
    timeSinceStart = millis()-timeAtStart;
    //println(timeSinceStart); for de bugging
  }
  greenAverage = greenTotal/greenCount;

//println(greenAverage); for de bugging
}

void serialEvent (Serial myPort) {
  int inByte=myPort.read();
  //0-255
  gsrValue=inByte;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I like to do for timers, is use IF statements and use millis() or a constantly updated variable 'm' right inside the condition:

```
int timeSinceStart;
int m;

void setup(){
  timeSinceStart = millis(); // initialize here so it only happens once
}

void draw(){
  m = millis(); // constantly update the variable

  if(timeSinceStart + 30000 < m){
    greenAverage = greenTotal/greenCount; // or whatever is outside while loop
    timeSinceStart = millis();
  }

  //Anything that went inside the while loop can go here, or above the IF

}
```

This makes it so around every 30 seconds, the background will change once, and you just re-update the timeSinceStart variable in there too. This way, it will only update when you want it to update and not constantly update and break the code.

I tend not to use while loops in processing as they usually cause headaches. Hope my example helps.

Answer (score 0):

May have found a way round this using an IF statement. I perhaps looked over the fact the draw function is itself a loop, so i was able to use a variation of

```
if (timeSinceStart < 5000) {
background(green);
}
```

within draw.

Comment: Yeah, you got it. `draw` loops and the stage is updated every time it is called. So in your first example, the code is getting 'stuck' in the while loop for the first 30 seconds. Since the draw function doesn't finish until the while loop completes you're not seeing any updates to the screen during that time.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with timed events in Processing you should not use while loops inside the draw() function. The draw() function itself is a while loop which updates the "screen" each frame.

So, what you should do is create a timer and let it do a switch for you inside the draw() function. In your case, if you want to start with a green screen, you do that in the setup() function, and then create a method for altering according to a timer in your draw() function.

This is a suggestion on how you could solve your particular problem. Just change the cycle variable according to your need. In your case it would be 30000.

```
boolean isGreen = true;
int startTime = 0;
int lastTime = 0;
int cycle = 1000; //the cycle you need

void setup() {
  size(200, 200);
  background(0, 255, 0); //green
}

void draw() {
  startTime = millis();

  if (startTime > lastTime + cycle) {
    if (isGreen) {
      background(255); //white
      isGreen = !isGreen;
    } else {
      background(0, 255, 0); //green
      isGreen = !isGreen;
    }
    lastTime = millis();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. and thanks everyone for your comments and help.